# Calculating the integral $ \int_{0}^{5} { \frac{|x-1|}{|x-2| + |x-4|} } dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, absolute-value

How do we calculate the following integral:

$$ \int_{0}^{5} { \frac{|x-1|}{|x-2| + |x-4|} } dx$$

Comment: With absolute values, the most reliable method is to eliminate them by suitably splitting the domain of integration.

Comment: Hint: subdivide the interval $\,[0,5]\,$ in subintervals where you can be sure of the sign of each expression within absolute value.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: @IshanBanerjee I was thinking the same.

Comment: I upvoted the question because I don't think it's a particularly bad question, compared to some we get.

Answer (score 6):

Hint:

$$\int_0^5\ldots=\int_0^1\ldots+\int_1^2\ldots+\int_2^4\ldots+\int_4^5\ldots$$

Answer (score 4):

HINT:  $$|x-a|=\begin{cases} 
      x-a &\text{ if } x-a\ge 0 \text{ i.e., if } x\ge a\ \\
      -(x-a) &\text{ if } x-a<0 
   \end{cases}$$